# Woocommerce Image Size catalog

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, image-size

I got a problem. I don't know how to explain it clearly but the problem is when I hover on a product the details are 'flowing out' or something like that. The theme I use is Galleria. It is a child theme from Storefront.

Here is the pics:

Without hover
[image]

With the hover
[image]

Comment: Link to the website?

Comment: Does the image fill the container? Isn't it too small - check the width in WC settings, I think it will be this case. Otherwise, it could be missing: `display:relative` on the wrapping element for each item.

Comment: @kybernaut.cz is position:relative not display :)

Comment: @Droid yeah an example online would be nice

Comment: @Nick, you're right, I'm probably too sleepy.

Comment: @Nick well I new to css, would it be okay if I add it to the end of style.css ?

Comment: @Skai the website works perfectly fine on chrome...where are you seeing this issue? and what you mean with the end of the css? it doesn't matter where you add it in the css file itself, it depends on a bunch of other factors handled by wordpress. As long as you enqueue it the right way, you can put it anywhere in the right file

Comment: @Nick I see it in the homepage

Comment: Thank you @Skai I really do not understand the problem you're having can you please explain more on what you mean by "flowing out"?

Comment: @Droid well thank you for the response, uhm I really don't know how to explain it but can you look the hovered image and it's caption?

Comment: @Skai I do not see any captions on the image :/

Comment: I mean the details the price and name when you hover on it. It is bigger than the image @Droid

Comment: This is confusing.. what are you trying to make it look like? I don't see the issue :/

Comment: @Droid please look at the image size, it is smaller than the black field